# Does `ShapeStyle` inherit from `View`?

Tags: swiftui

In the official document about [ShapeStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle), there is nowhere to find out whether `ShapeStyle` inherits from something else or not, is it a `View`?

Comment: No, it is not a View.

Comment: @Asperi but [Color](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color) inherits from `ShapeStyle` and `Color` conforms to `View` too, why?

Comment: Both are protocols, so Color is-a View and Color is-a ShapeStyle, but not Color is-a ShapeStyle is-a View. You can conform concrete type to as many protocols as you want  - theoretically, I'm not sure about 1 million :).

Comment: @Asperi I totally agree with you, but the official document is very confusing, isn't it? - "[A way to turn a shape into a view.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle)"

Comment: Ah, I'm kind of getting it, I think I've been putting my focus in the wrong place. The line above should be read: "a WAY to turn a shape into a view", not "a way to turn a shape into a VIEW" 

Comment: But IMO the official document is, nonetheless, still very confusing. `Shape` is already a `View`, isn't it? Why bother turning it into a view AGAIN?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of `ShapeStyle`. As you can see, it conforms to `View` protocol.

```
/// A way to turn a shape into a view.
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ShapeStyle {
}

@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ShapeStyle {

    /// Return a new paint value matching `self` except using `rect` to
    /// map unit-space coordinates to absolute coordinates.
    @inlinable public func `in`(_ rect: CGRect) -> some ShapeStyle

}

/// Default View.body implementation to fill a Rectangle with `self`.
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ShapeStyle where Self : View, Self.Body == _ShapeView<Rectangle, Self> {

    public var body: _ShapeView<Rectangle, Self> { get }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you point out exactly where in the definition is `ShapeStyle` inheriting from `View`?